# If the square of every element of a ring is in the center, must the ring be commutative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with identity such that the square of any element belongs to the center of $R$. Is it necessary true that $R$ is commutative?

(I can show that for any $x,y\in R$, $2(xy-yx) =0 $ but I cannot prove commutativity of $R$.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a counterexample.  Consider the $\mathbb{F}_2$-algebra $R$ generated by two elements $x,y$ modulo relations that $x^2=y^2=0$ and every word of length $3$ formed by $x$ and $y$ is $0$.  Explicitly, $R$ has $\{1,x,y,xy,yx\}$ as a basis and any product of basis elements that would give a word not in this set is $0$.  Since $xy\neq yx$, $R$ is not commutative.

I now claim that the square of every element of $R$ is central.  Indeed, for an element $r=a+bx+cy+dxy+eyx\in R$ ($a,b,c,d,e\in\mathbb{F}_2$) we have
$$r^2 = a^2 + bcxy + bcyx.$$ To show that such an element is central, it suffices to show that $xy+yx$ is central.  But this is trivial, since $xy+yx$ annihilates both $x$ and $y$ on both sides.

Comment: Since you are giving a specific example, I'm assuming that the answer is no, it doesn't have to be commutative?

Comment: Ok just got that it's not commutative from your edit, was confused on that before lol since I thought it was commutative.

Comment: Thanks, Out of curiosity, is there a matrix representation for your algebra ? I mean an explicit matrix ring example.

Comment: @Sara.T: Well, you can just let it act on itself by left multiplication to get a representation by $5\times 5$ matrices.  If you further mod out $yx$ there is a nice representation by $3\times 3$ matrices though, with $x$ being $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $y$ being $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.  They generate the ring of upper-triangular $3\times 3$ matrices with constant diagonal.

Comment: @EricWofsey thanks, I like that.

Comment: Does the ring you describe have 32 elements? And when you "mod out $yx$" it has 16 elements?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Yes, that's correct.